# Get file from MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT intent

Tags: android

I'm using a function called takePicture to take an image and store it to a file.  I'm then passing that file to an intent.  I can't figure out how to get the file out of the intent in `onActivityResult`.  The Android docs say

> The client app that receives the content URI can open the file and
>   access its contents by calling ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor to
>   get a ParcelFileDescriptor.

I just have no idea how to implement that.

```
public void takePicture(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(FallingActivity.this,   this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", getOutputMediaFile());

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_TAKE_PHOTO);
}
```

Here's how I've got `onActivityResult` set up.  My end goal is to get the file from the intent in `onActivityResult` and convert it to a Uri so I can pass it to Adobe's Aviary editor.  Currently when the Adobe Aviary editor loads I get a message saying "There was an error downloading the image".  Can anyone help me figure out why?

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            Uri selectedImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(FallingActivity.this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", getOutputMediaFile());

            Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(this)
                .setData(selectedImage)
                .build();

        imageEditorIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent, RESULT_AVIARY_EDIT);

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I can't figure out how to get the file out of the intent in onActivityResult

There is no file to be gotten out of the `Intent`. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return anything when you provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, other than the OK/cancelled status.

You know where the photo is supposed to be. It is in the result of `getOutputMediaFile()`. You need to hold onto that value, such as via a field on your activity or fragment. Be sure to save it across configuration changes, such as via the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help show me how I might go about doing that?  How do I access the photo in onActivityResult?

Comment: @Canadian: It would help if you would explain what you do not understand. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrating how to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `FileProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help so far.  I apologize for any obvious questions but I'm very new to all of this.  I've updated my code above based on the sample project you provided.  When the Adobe Aviary Editor loads I get an Android warning saying.  "Attention: There was an error downloading the image, please try again later".  Any idea why?

Thanks again!

Comment: @Canadian: You need to `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on your `imageEditorIntent`. Otherwise, Adobe Aviary Editor has no rights to access your content. See [this line in my sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Camera/FileProvider/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/camcon/MainActivity.java#L123).

Comment: I've added that line and I'm still getting the same error.  I've updated the code above.  

Do I need to add the following to my gradle file?

'dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.5.0'
}'

Comment: @Canadian: " Do I need to add the following to my gradle file? 'dependencies { compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.5.0' }'" -- no, because you are not using my `StreamProvider`. Perhaps Adobe Aviary Editor does not support `content` schemes. You'll have to ask them.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll check with Adobe and report back.

Answer (score -1):

I might be late providing a solution..

**EXTRA_OUTPUT** extra will not return any data back.. so the check inside onActivityResult method **(data != null) will not work** bcoz the data is always null with that EXTRA_OUTPUT instead you can do the remaining checks as you have already done (checking request and result codes).

Hope it helped someone.